# Ho to get the helm index (list of tags) of a artifact registry (for argocd)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gitlab, helm3, argocd, google-artifact-registry

We are using Argocd for our CICD in our cluster.

Currently we are switching our Helm repository from the Gitlab Container Registry to the GCP Artifact registry.

There is one problem I am facing. It was possible to fetch from Gitlab the whole list of available versions and choose the one we need in the UI dropdown of argocd itself. I assume "helm repo index" is used somewhere behind the scenes.

I would like the same behaviour from the GCP Artifact registry. But all tutorials I found specify a concrete version of the HELM archive they want to use in the argocd configurations. This disallows changing the versions in the argocd UI.

Is it possible to use the  GCP Artifact registry the same way we were using Gitlabs Container Registry?

Comment: Artifact Registry does not have a UI since it relies on Google's CLI.  There will be no dropdown menu, but you can use labels and tags to organize the repositories.  Labels can be used to group repositories by development stage or by team for automation.  Is this something that can be useful to you?

Comment: @AndresFiescoCasasola I am not speaking about a dropdown in the Artifact registry. I am speaking about one in Argocd. I want that argocd receives a index.yaml with a list of all possible options of helm charts in the artifact registry. 

And btw, Artifact registry has an UI:
https://console.cloud.google.com/artifacts